# How to connect with remote MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, database, remote-access

so I tried to connect to my local host with the 3306 port, and it works fine. Now, I'm using my second computer to connect to the database remotely.

1. I use the jdbc:mysql://192.168.15.25:3306/yourdatabase type.
2. My two computers are actually using the same IP.
3. The trace says communication failure. I followed the problem, and it happens when I try to get the connection from the DriverManager.
4. I did not touch the firewall at all.
5. I did not write any permissions to users, as there are no users, just the admin.

Comment: Try checking your admins and/or users on the mysql database. If I remember correctly, it defaults to root@localhost as the only user, so no external communication can happen.

Comment: Check that mysql is [configured to listen for connections on an external interface](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address). Often the default configuration is set to listen on `127.0.0.1` which means that you can only connect from the same machine.

Answer (score 2):

Two computers can't have same IP. Check the second for IP address using `ifconfig` command (if you have *nix system).

Comment: this is true unless they are not on the same network and both have the same private ip address in which case you need not target the private ip address but instead the public ip address or the next hop address with some forwarders configured

Answer (score 0):

Follow this instructions:

```
Client PC:(sample ip: 192.168.0.105 want yo connect to mysql server on 192.168.0.172)
- Java app: user: dbuser, pass: dbpass, host: 192.168.0.172

Mysql Server PC:
- On mysql console: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO dbuser@192.168.0.105 identified by "dbpass";
  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now you have all set to make a remote conection from your client to your mysql server.